# Efficiently search for valid location in 2D array

Tags: algorithm, performance, search, multidimensional-array, flood-fill

Quick note: feel free to answer in any language of choice

I want to quickly and efficiently search a 2D array for the first valid location to place an object. For a location to be considered valid it means that the object of specified height and width will fit in an area marked with only 0s. For this case you can imagine the object we specify has a height and width > 1 and there will exist a valid location in the 2d array. For example, imagine I have the following 2D array

```
[
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 [0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

And an object with height 3 and width 3, the function should return   An object with the following row and column as the first valid location `{row: 2, col:4}`. First valid location refers to the top left corner where an object of unknown height and width can fit onto the 2D array and cover an area where every element is a 0.

Also maybe the best we can do is n*m and have to search every element. I just have wishful thinking that there are areas I can skip over since I know they won’t work. Using the example above I tried searching starting from the width of object. In this case I would begin my search from (0,2). I would search down to (2,2) before moving over to the left and searching there. Once I find a collision at (1,1) I know I do not have to search (0,0) or (1,0). What I want to solve are the following two points:

1. How to be efficient and not re check areas I’ve already checked.
2. How to be efficient and not check areas that can’t possibly fit my object.

my thought process has been some sort of bfs/dfs algorithm, but I run into problems where I check areas that I know aren’t valid. I need a way to efficiently know what isn’t valid to avoid spending time on those areas

Comment: "areas that I know aren’t valid": *how* do you know these?

Comment: How efficient is efficient enough? Would you mind examining every cell once?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI so originally what I was doing was examine every cell once. But sitting down and drawing an example with pen and paper I started to believe this wasn’t needed. For example, one of my thought processes was starting from the width of the element and moving down and left. So in my example I started at (0,2) went down to (2,2) before moving over to the left. Once I found a collision at (1,1) I thought I wouldn’t need to check any of the positions on far left since I know they won’t be valid and can instead start again from (0,4). Maybe I’m wishful tho, and n*m is the most efficien

Comment: @ScottHunter you can read the message I just replied to n.m.couldbeanAi, but to summarize. An area isn’t valid if my object of a certain height and width overlaps and element in the 2D array that has a 1

Comment: By "first valid location" do you mean to return the top left corner of the rectangle that has the lowest row index and lowest column value, with that priority? Also it'd be helpful to post your constraints on the 2d array dimensions along with the height and width.

Comment: @wLui155 yes first valid location means return top left corner where an object of unknown width and height fits into the 2d array (fits meaning it covers an area where every element is a 0). As for constraints, there are no constraints on the size of the 2d array. The only information is that the object we are trying to fit has a height and width > 0 and there is a valid location for the object in the 2d array

Comment: Which is a typical array size? How many locations would you request?

Comment: @Ripi2 unknown array size. We just know there is always one valid location for the object. I just want the first valid location. There could be many but we just care about the first working our way down from top left to bottom right

Comment: For small amout of locations I'd go with the cell-by-cell method. For bigs arrays and zillions of locations I can propose something. I expect the array to change only due to locations.

Comment: @Ripi2 ok let’s go for a case where a million cells exist

Comment: By "the best we can do is n * m and have to search every element", do you mean a brute force approach where a rectangle with the required height and width is checked for each point in the 2d array? If so, it sounds like your approach will actually be O(n * m * height * width). I think there's a way to get O(n * m) performance if you don't mind traversing the entire grid a few times though.

Comment: @wLui155 would you mind sharing some code where it is 0(n*m) and what you mean with traversing the grid a few times as an answer? I had a feeling that might be the case and I might have just been having wishful thinking on improvement

Comment: Regarding @wLui155's question about "first valid location" can we make that more precise by saying that if `[i,j]` and `[p,q]` are two valid locations, `[i,j]` precedes `[p,q]` if `i < p` or if `i = p` and `j < q`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the following: For each row setup an array of "zero" (valid) positions with its lenght. lets call it [pos,len]

```
0 [0,6]
1 [0,1],[2,3],[6,1]
2 [0,3],[4,3]
3 [0,1],[2,5]
4 [0,7]
5 [0,7]
6 [0,7]
```

When you are looking for a rectangle of 3,3  you are left with

```
1 [2,3]
2 [0,3],[4,3]
3 [2,5]
4 [0,7]
5 [0,7]
6 [0,7]
```

As you want a height of (3,3), rows should have the correct overlap in postions with lenght. starting with row1 [2,3]. do we have in row2 [0,3] an overlap where:

```
pos2 + len2 - pos1 >=3 and pos1 + len1 - pos2 => 3

this would give us 0 + 3 - 2 >= 3 and 2 + 3 - 0 => 3 FALSE
```

now we can take the next in row2 [4,3] what gives us another FALSE

time to forget about row1 and move to row2[0,3] compared to row3 [2,5]

etc, etc.

When yo have 2 times TRUE, you have found your position. 2 as it is the rectangle height (3) -1

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a big array, filled with `1s` and `0s` that changes only due to a location of an object in a available rectangle in this array.

The first step is compute all available rectangles for all objects.

We use containers for each object size.

For example, a container for objects of size (3x4) will store (x,y) coordinates in the array for the top-left corner of each object. Use another container for (2x4) objects; another for (5x1); and so on.

Notice that locations can overlap. Perhaps a (2,3) location for a (4,5) object overlaps with (3,3) location for a same (4,5) object or with a (1,2) object. Don't care.

The containers can be sorted by some criterium: minimum x, minimum y, minimum x+y, etc.

The point is when we search for a given object (NxM) we just search in its (NxM) due container, and get the first one if it's sorted.

Once we do the location, the affected containers must be updated.

We must implement a box-box intersection (which is simple, working only with corners) to tell if a location in a container must be deleted, and to tell if new smaller locations appear.

The trick is that working with sorted containers is much quicker that checking cell by cell. But this is not true for small arrays or just a bunch of locations.